# Summing all items contained in the Controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm just beginning with AngularJS. I'd need to upgrade this shopping cart example from AngularJS' book so that the total of all (items.price*item.quantity) is displayed at the bottom of the page. Which is the recommended way to achieve it ?

```
<HTML ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function CartController($scope) {
                $scope.items = [{
                    title: 'Paint pots',
                    quantity: 8,
                    price: 3.95
                },
                {
                    title: 'Pebbles',
                    quantity: 5,
                    price: 6.95
                }];

                $scope.remove = function(index) {
                    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='CartController'>
        <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
            <span>{{item.title}}</span>
            <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
            <span>{{item.price}}</span>
            <span>{{item.price * item.quantity}}</span>
            <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8j5pMZRmvtLQHlW9C50c?p=preview):

Create a function which iterates all items like so:

```
$scope.sum = function(){
  return $scope.items.reduce(function(p,item){
    return p + (item.quantity * item.price)
  },0)
}
```

Markup:

```
<span>Sum : {{ sum() }}</span>
```

read more about [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: While this gets the job done, I don't think it represents a good design pattern.  Angular provides lots of facilities, like filters, to decouple this kind of requirements into reusable utilities.

Comment: @JoelSkrepnek I also use filters in my apps when it fits. For this particular answer it doesn't, why? because in his question he doesn't even use a module, just putting the controller on the global scope ( which is a terrible practice ) so I try to fit my answer to the level of the question without refactoring it too much.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be a good candidate for a 'sum' [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter).  The bonus of writing a sum filter is that it's generic and you can use it anywhere in your app.

The simpliest implementation would take as input an array of objects and a string parameter that is the property on each object to sum.

```
angular.module('app')
       .filter('sum', function () {
           return function (input, propertyToSum) {
               var sum = 0;
               angular.forEach(input, function (value, key) {
                   sum = sum + value [propertyToSum];
               }
               return sum;
           }
       });
```

Then use it like this:

```
<span>Sum: {{ items | sum:'price' }}</span>
```

Not 100% on the syntax here.  Build it in fiddler and let me know if it doesn't comes through.

There's a whole host of assumptions being made here that tests and whatnot should cover.  But that's the basic idea.

You could also use a utility library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) in conjunction with this filter, which provides plenty of useful operations on collections.

Answer (score 1):

Have a total property on the scope with a watch on the item collection:

```
$scope.total = 0;

$scope.$watch( 'items', updateTotal, true );

function updateTotal(){
    $scope.total = 0;
    angular.forEach( $scope.items, function(item){
        $scope.total += (item.price * item.quantity);
    });
}
```

And in the view:

```
<p>Total {{total}}</p>
```